# modify interaction drop marker event

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I use OL 4.5.0 to display pois at google and osm maps. To move these pois I use the modify interaction which can be activated or deactivated by buttons on my maps. When the user deactivates the modify interaction all marker positions are saved. This works fine.
Now i want to ask the user if the new marker position should be saved when dropping the marker on the map.

1. I can't reach (or find) a modify drop marker event. Which event I should use for this exactly?
2. Is it possible to activate the modify event even by trying to move a marker? A single click on a marker opens a popup so I can't use the single click event of the browser.

Comment: By "modify event" do you mean "modify interaction" https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.interaction.Modify.html ?  What logic are you using to drop a marker on the map?  The drag and drop interaction https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragAndDrop.html has an `addfeatures` event.

Comment: You are right with the interaction

Comment: That question showed me the right way! I use a dragbox interaction and there you can handle the drop event while modify interaction is active.